# In Gnome, is there a way to just get search prompt without windows

Tags: gnome-shell

So I like the search in the overview view in Gnome 3. The issue I am having is that opening the overview takes a bit of time if I have many windows open because all the windows have to be scaled and made smaller for the overview view.

So I would like to have overview separate from searching. Overview could still have a search, but I would also like just a view where search prompt and search results are shown, without any windows being processed at all. Ideally, they would just stay under, visible as they are.